# Wi-fi camera connection mechanism

Tags: wireless-networking

I've recently been experimenting with an ezviz CTQ2C wi-fi camera.

To connect this to my network, I start the ezviz app on my phone, enter the wi-fi credentials (this is just the WPA2 password) on my phone and ezviz somehow sends this to the camera.

The camera can then connect to the wi-fi network.

How is ezviz transporting the credentials to the camera before the camera is connected to the wi-fi network?

Comment: I believe this is off-topic here.

Comment: Bluetooth? Try turning that off your confirm, you can also check the apps permissions

Comment: I'm thinking WiFi/802.11 ad-hoc, meaning your phone disconnects from your home WiFi/router & connects directly to the camera. Google Chromecast is initially setup like that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking [Wireless ad-hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) (or [WiFi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct)), meaning your phone disconnects from your home WiFi/router & connects directly to the camera. [Google Chromecast is initially setup like that too](https://www.howtogeek.com/237403/how-to-setup-your-new-chromecast/). [Amazon page for ezviz CTQ2C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DLM9J2K) shows a [specification sheet](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71H81J5igHL.pdf) the says: `Wi-Fi: PairingSmartConfig (Wi-Fi One-Key Configuration)/AP paring`

If you're curious you could turn off your Wi-Fi & open the app to program cam & notice how it likely turns on your WiFi. Might also help to 'Forget' your home WiFi so that way the indication if WiFi is connected or not will help you visually see whats happening a bit more.

Comment: I had bluetooth disabled, so that's out.  I think you're correct about wi-fi direct, Android provides APIs to do this here:  https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.